# How can I search a folder which it's name contains specifc character in Python

Tags: python

I know I can use `GLOB` to Search Folder, but for example:

```
ssd = raw_input("input sth: ")
glob.glob('C:\Program Files\'+ssd)
```

this way only with exact folder name I can search the folder.

I saw something about using `*` but not sure how to use it.

I know the answers gonna be very easy but I'm a newbie so... please help.

Comment: Yes, it's easy.  Append `*` on both sides of the input variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As devnull commented, surround the input variable `ssd` with `*`:

```
glob.glob('C:\\Program Files\\*{}*'.format(ssd))
```

**Side Note**: You should escape backslashes as I did in above code, or use raw string literal.

```
glob.glob(r'C:\Program Files\*{}*'.format(ssd))
```

Comment: Hey it's you again, Thanks as always.